# link between QueryBuilder parameters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

```
public function Bycategorie($categorie)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
               ->select('u')
               ->where('u.categorie = :categorie')
               ->orderBy('u.id')
               ->setParameter('categorie',$categorie);
               return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I want to know what the link is between:
`$categorie`, `u` and the entity in which I'm working,

Comment: is categorie the entity or just the id? try both. sometimes the id will work and the entity will not. For example when you used another entity manager to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to Doctrine. About association mapping you can read [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

In your example relation can be One-to-One (in theory) or Many-to-One (many users can obtain the same category). Many-to-One relation is more preferable variant and has a logical explanation.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already worked with the Doctrine. Now i want to use the queryBuilder and i want to know the link between the parameters of createQueryBuilder and the field(attributes) of my entity in which i m working. please a help.

Answer (score 0):

helo, i have found what i was searching for.
my question was : what is the link between querybuilder parameters.
in my example i find that in the where clause (where('u.categorie =:categorie'))
'categorie' of the left(in the parenthesis)  must be a colum of a table in my database.
thanks for your helps.